# InputStream was closed - Libstream

Tags: java, android, libstreaming

I noticed a new problem with my application, that problem is about the libstream library, that's generate a package from the resource of camera with MediaRecorder or MediaCodec.

I'm using Dagger 2, Realm and ExoPlayer at my app, but I don't think it's a problem with these libraries...

But I'm at troubles, when I start and try to connect with my server, this library returns it:

```
08-19 15:47:17.610  20235-23761/com.myhappyapp W/System.err﹕java.io.IOException: This InputStream was closed
08-19 15:47:17.610  20235-23761/com.myhappyapp W/System.err﹕ at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtp.MediaCodecInputStream.read(MediaCodecInputStream.java:92)
08-19 15:47:17.610  20235-23761/com.myhappyapp W/System.err﹕ at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtp.H264Packetizer.fill(H264Packetizer.java:245)
08-19 15:47:17.610  20235-23761/com.myhappyapp W/System.err﹕ at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtp.H264Packetizer.send(H264Packetizer.java:156)
08-19 15:47:17.610  20235-23761/com.myhappyapp W/System.err﹕ at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtp.H264Packetizer.run(H264Packetizer.java:122)
08-19 15:47:17.610  20235-23761/com.myhappyapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

It started suddenly, in older versions of the app was not occurring. :(